# Pages interchanged; unwanted

Tags: page-breaking

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass[
  danish,
  dvipsnames
]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[
  hmargin=2.4cm,
  vmargin=3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \centering
  \begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-2.9,-6.93)(2.9,10.43)
   \psset{
     lightsrc=viewpoint,
     viewpoint=40 -10 0 rtp2xyz,
     Decran=100,
     object=tore,
     r0=0.2,
     action=none
   }
    \psSolid[r1=1,  ngrid=10 50,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=blue,  name=R1](0,0,3)
    \psSolid[r1=0.9,ngrid=10 45,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=green, name=R2](0,0,1.5)
    \psSolid[r1=0.8,ngrid=10 40,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=red,   name=R3](0,0,0.2)
    \psSolid[r1=0.7,ngrid=10 35,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=yellow,name=R4](0,0,-0.9)
    \psSolid[r1=0.6,ngrid=10 30,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=Purple,name=R5](0,0,-1.8)
    \psSolid[
      object=fusion,
      base=R1 R2 R3 R4 R5,
      linewidth=0.2pt,
      linecolor=black!60,
      action=draw**
    ]
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}
\newpage

\noindent Tredjekoordinaten~$z_{i}$ til centrum for torus nummer~$i$, regnet fra toppen, er givet ved
\begin{equation*}
 z_{i} =
  \begin{cases}
    z_{1}                                                       & \text{for } i = 1,\\
    z_{1} - r_{1} - 2r_{2} - \dotsb - 2r_{i-1} - r_{i} + 2(i - 1)r & \text{for } i > 1,
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
hvor $r$ er den konstante radius af hvert "`torusr{\o}r"' og $r_{i}$ er radius af den $i$'te torus.

Bem{\ae}rk, at startv{\ae}rdien~$z_{1}$ skal \emph{v{\ae}lges}.

\end{document}
```

(Compile using XeLaTeX.)

Why are the two pages interchanged and how do I fix this?

P.S. Feel free to change/add tags.

Comment: Use `\clearpage` instead of `\newpage`; but why are you using `figure` in the first place? A `center` environment would do as well.

Comment: The purpose of float environments like figure is to float. Don't use figure if you don't want this. Or use `\clearpage` instead of `\newpage` to force the output of the float.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! The `figure` is a habit to get the correct vertical spacing around the figure.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you; I'll try to remember this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that the `figure` environment is put in the float queue; since it is not possible to print it “here”, “top” or ”bottom”, the float is delayed to a ”page” float, which is so output after the text.

You don't need a `figure` environment for an illustration without a caption, so a `center` environment will do as well.

Alternatively, issue `\clearpage`, which will end the page *and* flush the float queue.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
```

that allows to ignore the float parameters